# Compare column headers and return difference

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the difference in column headers between the two sheets - BOM and Material Sheet using the VBA script.
The strange thing is both the sheets are available in the Excel workbook. I tried to change the sheet name but it gives the error "Subscript out of range". However, when I changed the sheet name to sheet1 the error moved to the next sheet (I tried with a different name but didn't solve it) - however, I can't do more.

Below is the script, could anyone please help here?
Thank you.

```
Sub CompareTableHeaders()
    Dim bomSheet As Worksheet
    Dim materialSheet As Worksheet
    Dim bomHeader As Range
    Dim materialHeader As Range
    Dim differentColumns As Range
    Dim columnName As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet variables
    Set bomSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM")
    Set materialSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Material")
    
    ' Get the last column with data in the BOM sheet
    Set bomHeader = bomSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)
    
    ' Get the last column with data in the Material sheet
    Set materialHeader = materialSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)
    
    ' Compare the table headers and store the different column names
    For Each bomCell In bomHeader
        columnName = bomCell.Value
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(materialHeader, columnName) = 0 Then
            If differentColumns Is Nothing Then
                Set differentColumns = bomCell
            Else
                Set differentColumns = Union(differentColumns, bomCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next bomCell
    
    ' Display the different column names
    If Not differentColumns Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Different Columns: " & differentColumns.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "No different columns found"
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried to change the sheet name but it gives the error "Subscript out of range". However, when I changed the sheet name to sheet1 the error moved to the next sheet (I tried with a different name but didn't solve it) - however, I can't do more.

Comment: Let me guess: Your code is in a different workbook than your data? Maybe in your personal workbook? Try `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`

Answer (score 0):

Usually "Subscript out of range" occurred when you try to access a sheet or range that doesn't exist. Try below edited code.

```
Sub CompareTableHeaders()
    Dim bomSheet As Worksheet
    Dim materialSheet As Worksheet
    Dim bomHeader As Range, materialHeader As Range
    Dim differentColumns As String
    Dim bomCell As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet variables
    Set bomSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM")
    Set materialSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Material")
    
    ' Get the header range in the BOM sheet
    Set bomHeader = bomSheet.Range("A1", bomSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
    
    ' Get the header range in the Material sheet
    Set materialHeader = materialSheet.Range("A1", materialSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
    
    ' Compare the table headers and store the different column names
    For Each bomCell In bomHeader
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(materialHeader, bomCell.Value) = 0 Then
            differentColumns = differentColumns & bomCell.Value & ", "
        End If
    Next bomCell
    
    ' Display the different column names
    If differentColumns <> "" Then
        'Remove the trailing comma and space
        differentColumns = Left(differentColumns, Len(differentColumns) - 2)
        MsgBox "Different Columns: " & differentColumns
    Else
        MsgBox "No different columns found"
    End If
End Sub
```